# How to use facebook app token and replace the page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

Currently I am using a facebook page access token to retrieve data from a fb-page. This token has multiple permissions (read_insight, ads_read...).

If I request data in my Chrome browser I do this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/3865617700180122_3899200346821857?fields=id,message,from,created_time,permalink_url&access_token={MY_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

As excpected, I get the data!

However, since the page_access_token is based on my private facebook account, I want to use the app token. If I understand correctly, this token is NOT related to my personal fb-profile. This means, even if I am not admin of my facebook app, everybody who ownes this app token can retrieve data from the page. This is what I need!!!!

However, if I replace the page_access_token with my app token I can not retrieve the data anymore:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/3865617700180122_3899200346821857?fields=id,message,from,created_time,permalink_url&access_token={APP_TOKEN}`

Comment: You would have to sumbit your app for access to the Page Public Content Access feature then first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: _“everybody who ownes this app token can retrieve data from the page”_ - that “everybody” should be only you to begin with, or other admins/developers of your app. You’re not planing to expose this to any outside parties, right?

Comment: But I am talking about my own page. I am the admin of this page. According to my understanding I already have all permissions needed to retriev the data. Why can I not simply switch between page_access_token and app_token?

Comment: Because the app token has no association to your personal account, that was allowed to grant access to the page in the first place.

Comment: I am planning to retrieve data from my own fb-page. Since we are a team of 3 people and one day I want to delete my private fb-account, I want remove the connection beween the page access token and my personal account. This is why I want to use the app token. This token works for all persons of my team no matter if I am the admin or not

Comment: Well, you can’t. (Unless you submit for the Page Public Content Acess feature - which I doubt they will grant you for a purpose like this.) You _need_ to use a page token to prove that you have admin access to the page, and a page access token is always tied to a specific user.

Comment: Very interessting! So when I leave my team and I leave the app admin rights, my generated page access token will not work. I find it hard that facebook doen't provide a simple solution for this. I think I am not the only person who has this problem. If I understand correctly, somebody else has to become admin and generate new page access token when I leave